# How to re-enable automatic new hardware notifications in KDE 4.2?

Tags: linux, kubuntu, kde-4

I turned it off because it was "spamming" me with information about plasma sound issues, but it appears that without it system also doesn't mount usb storage devices automatically. How to bring it back?

Comment: @depesz: How did you "turn it off"? ... be more precise ...

Comment: @avelldiroll - clicked on the icon in taskbar with right mouse button, and chose to close it. I don't recall how it was named, so can't really be more precised. Didn't uninstall anything - just closed the app. Reboot doesn't help - i must have clicked something like "don't start next time".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you might have remove the **Device Notifier widget**.

To add a new **Device Notifier widget** to your panel you need to *right click* on a the far right element of the pannel and select *Add Widgets ...* from the presented menu.

Then select *Device Notifier* in the widget list and click on the button labeled *Add Widget*.

Comment: It helped a lot. Now I get nice notification where I can click, and then it will mount and open dolphin. How can I make it so it will automount and automatically open doplhin?

Comment: That's a known bug on kde4. For mor info see those: http://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=175611 http://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=164053 .  it might be fixed in karmic though.